# CSS: Keyframe animation disappears when hover away

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

My div has an animation on it's border when hovering.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

div:hover {
   animation: blink 750ms forwards;
}


@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  33% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }

  66% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

The animation is works fine as expected but when I hover off the div, the animation brakes suddenly. I want to keep the animation complete even though the cursor is away.

I've tried to add the `transition: border-color 300ms;` on the div but still it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition:1000s; /*block the change*/
}

div:hover {
   animation: blink 750ms; /*remove forwards*/
   /*Add the last state of the animation*/
   border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
   /*---*/
   transition:.5s; /*make the change fast on hover*/
}


@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  33% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }

  66% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**UPDATE**

To make sure the animation will end, you need to keep the hover state. An idea is to consider a pseudo-element that will cover all the screen to be sure you will keep the hover until the end:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

div.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition:1000s; /*block the change*/
  position:relative;
}

div.box:hover {
   animation: blink 750ms; /*remove forwards*/
   /*Add the last state of the animation*/
   border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
   /*---*/
   transition:.5s; /*make the change fast on hover*/
}
div.box:hover:before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
  animation:disappear 0.1s 0.75s forwards;
}

@keyframes disappear {
  to {bottom:100%;}
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  33% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }

  66% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Look like the white border remains after the animation and also when I hover away the animation breaks. I want the animation to complete.